# Add days on onchange event in Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

how to add number of days to textbox2 once the onchange event of textbox1 was triggered, using lotusscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually want to keep adding to "textbox2" whenever the user moves out of "textbox1"? Or do you want to re-compute some formula into textbox2?  In the notes client, you can define  "textbox2" as a computed field and then force the form to re-compute all computed fields when the user leaves textbox1, by adding code to the exiting event of textbox1:

```
... 
dim ws as notesUIWorkspace, uidoc as notesUIDocument 
set uiDoc = ws.currentDocument 
call uiDoc.refresh() 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

lotusscript only for Notes client. If you use  Notes DB as web app - use javascript. But you can use javascript for Notes client, you must use onBlur event script. This script setting "Run" same for Client and Web.

Example:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.textbox2.value = form.textbox1.value + " // this value from textbox1 field
```

Comment: @valmont- yes I am using notes client only, how to do this on notes client? I have this one Sub OnChange(Source as Field) textbox1=@Adjust(textbox2;0;0;5;0;0;0) End Sub, but it seems an error occurs @ Unexpected expression

Comment: sorry I am a newbie in lotus notes

Comment: in textfield1 onBlur event add Alert(this.value). Add this on "Run Web Javascript"  and "Run Client Javascript"

Comment: whats version of Lotus Notes?

Comment: by the way, the  textbox2 is having a type datetime and it was computed

Comment: BTW, `@Adjust` is a formula expression: you can't use that in a Lotusscript event "as is", you need to place it in an `Evaluate` expression